# How can I use jQuery validation with the "chosen" plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-chosen

I have some `<select>` inputs using the [chosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) that I want to validate as "required" on the client side. Since "chosen" hides the actual select element and creates a widget with divs and spans, native HTML5 validation doesn't seem to work properly. The form won't submit (which is good), but the error message is not shown, so the user has no idea what's wrong (which is not good).

I've turned to the jQuery validation plugin (which I planned on using eventually anyways) but haven't had any luck so far. Here's my [test case](http://jsfiddle.net/mrZF5/4/):

```
<form>
    <label>Name: <input name="test1" required></label>
    <label>Favorite Color:
        <select name="test2" required>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="green">Green</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').chosen();
    $('form').validate();
});
```

This is letting the `select` through with an empty value, without validating or showing the error message. When I comment out the `chosen()` line, it works fine.

How can I validate `chosen()` inputs with the jQuery validation plugin, and show the error message for invalid ones?

Comment: Check [this plugin](https://github.com/elclanrs/jq-idealforms) out. Not really a solution but you might want to give it a try.

Comment: @elclanrs: Thanks but I'd like to stick with the de facto jQuery validation library for now, especially at this point in the project (trying to wrap up). Maybe in a future project.

Comment: This post solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387553/chosen-js-and-validate-jquery

Simple and elegant.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

jQuery validate ignores the hidden element, and since the Chosen plugin adds `visibility:hidden` attribute to the select, try:

`$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ":hidden:not(select)" }) //for all select`

OR

`$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ":hidden:not(.chosen-select)" }) //for all select having class .chosen-select`

Add this line just before `validate()` function. It works fine for me.

Comment: Where did you put this line? It doesn't seem to work for me :/

Comment: just above the JQuery validate() function.

Comment: Worked for me! Definitely the simplest solution.

Comment: Because all my chosen selects have the class `.chosen-select` I find it better to use `$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ":hidden:not(.chosen-select)" });`. Otherwise this would mean all hidden selects would be validated.

Comment: Works perfectly! I added it in my header with `<script type='text/javascript' >
    $.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ":hidden:not(select)" })
</script>` and works good

Comment: @Anupal: this code seems to work perfectly if you have only a single panel with chosen enabled elements. I have two panels which both have a chosen enabled element and this line does not work for me `form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden:not('select.chosen-select')"`

Comment: I have 2 chosen selects within a form and the first option worked for me, while the second did not.

Comment: Perfect! Was looking out for this since ages :)

Comment: hello guys, I have a problem with the focus of **jqueryvalidation**, doesn't work on the **chosen** fields, do you know how solve that problem ?

Answer (score 19):

jQuery validation isn't going to pick up elements that are hidden, but you can force it to validate individual elements. Bit of a hack, but the following will work:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    if(!$('[name="test2"]').valid()) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

To select only "chosen" elements you can use `$('.chzn-done')`

Comment: It seems that the `e.preventDefault()` isn't even necessary, just calling `$("element").valid()`. I used [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/mrZF5/5/) and it seems to work perfectly: `$('form').on('submit', function() {$('.chzn-done').valid();});`. Thanks for the info.

Comment: `.chzn-done` is no longer added to "chosen" elements as of Chosen 1.0

Answer (score 5):

in mine.

my form has class 'validate'
and every input element has class 'required'
html code:

```
<form id="ProdukProdukTambahForm" class="validate form-horizontal" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/produk-review/produk/produkTambah" novalidate="novalidate">
     <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="sku">SKU</label>
        <div class="controls">
           <input id="sku" class="required span6" type="text" name="sku">
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="control-group">
        <label for="supplier" class="control-label">Supplier</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select name="supplier" id="supplier" class='cho span6 {required:true} '>                                           
                <option value=''>-- PILIH --</option>
                <?php
                foreach ($result as $res)
                    {
                    echo '<option value="'.$res['tbl_suppliers']['kode_supplier'].'">'.$res['tbl_suppliers']['nama_supplier'].'</option>';
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

and javascript code for choosen with jquery validation

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // - validation
    if($('.validate').length > 0){
        $('.validate').validate({
            errorPlacement:function(error, element){
                    element.parents('.controls').append(error);
            },
            highlight: function(label) {
                $(label).closest('.control-group').removeClass('error success').addClass('error');
            },
            success: function(label) {
                label.addClass('valid').closest('.control-group').removeClass('error success').addClass('success');
            },
            //validate choosen select (select with search)
            ignore: ":hidden:not(select)"
        });
    }
    // - chosen, add the text if no result matched
    if($('.cho').length > 0){
        $(".cho").chosen({no_results_text: "No results matched"});
    }
});
```

note:
if the input value is null, the class error will be append to parent 'div'

Answer (score 3):

//You can fix this by using another way to hide your chosen element. eg....

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $.validator.addMethod(     //adding a method to validate select box//
            "chosen",
            function(value, element) {
                return (value == null ? false : (value.length == 0 ? false : true))
            },
            "please select an option"//custom message
            );

    $("form").validate({
        rules: {
            test2: {
                chosen: true
            }
        }
    });
    $("[name='test2']").css("position", "absolute").css("z-index",   "-9999").chosen().show();

    //validation.....
    $("form").submit(function()
    {
        if ($(this).valid())
        {alert("valid");
    //some code here 
        }
        return false;

    });
});
```

Comment: This answer only works if you don't call .chosen().  There seems to be a bug (feature?) in the chosen library that when you activate a <select>, it hides it - so it no longer interacts with the validation rules.

Answer (score 3):

I had to place `$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ":hidden:not(.chosen-select)" })`
outside `$(document).ready(function())` in order to work with chosen.js.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10063394/4063622

Answer (score 2):

this simple CSS rule works on joomla 3's implementation of chosen

Chosen adds the class invalid to the hidden select input so use this to target the chosen select box

```
.invalid, .invalid + div.chzn-container a {
    border-color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: In my case, I've added **ul.chosen-choices**:

`.input-validation-error { border-color: red !important; } .input-validation-error, .input-validation-error + div.chosen-container ul.chosen-choices { border-color: red !important; }`.

Answer (score 1):

You might also running into trouble that error message is displayed before Chosen dropdownlist. I found out the solution to resolve this issue and paste my code here to share with you

HTML:

```
<label class="col-sm-3">Select sponsor level *</label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSponsorLevel" runat="server" CssClass="col-sm-4 required" ClientIDmode="Static" />
<label class="error" id="ddlSponsorLevel-error" for="ddlSponsorLevel"></label>
```

Javascript:

```
if (!$('#ddlSponsorLevel').valid()) {
       $('#ddlSponsorLevel-error').text("You must choose a sponsor level");
            return false;
}
```

Jquery Validation actually added a hidden label html element. We can re-define this element with same ID on different place to overwrite original place.

Answer (score 1):

I spent about a day working on this and had no luck at all! Then I looked at the source code Vtiger was using and found gold! Even though they were using older versions they had the key! you have to use

```
data-validation-engine="validate[required]"
```

If you don't and you have it where classes are passed through the class for the select gets applied to the chosen and it thinks that your chosen never gets updated. If you don't pass the class onto the chosen this should be a problem, BUT if you do this is the only way it will work.

This is with chosen 1.4.2 validationEngine 2.6.2 and jquery 2.1.4

```
// binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
jQuery("#FORMNAME").validationEngine({
    prettySelect : true,
    useSuffix: "_chosen"
    //promptPosition : "bottomLeft"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

@Anupal put me on the right path but somehow I needed a complex fix

## Enable `.chosen` to be considered

**javascript**

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ":hidden:not(.chosen)" })
```

Or any other name you give to your chosen's. This is global configuration. Consider setting on top level

## Create custom rule for chosen

Thanks to [BenG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33941303/1358777)

**html**

```
<select id="field" name="field" class="chosen" data-rule-chosen-required="true">
    <option value="">Please select…</option>
</select>
```

**javascript**

Again, global configuration for `$.validator` object. Can be put next to the previous command

```
$.validator.addMethod('chosen-required', function (value, element, requiredValue) {
    return requiredValue == false || element.value != '';
}, $.validator.messages.required);
```

Comment: hello guys, I have a problem with the focus of **jqueryvalidation**, doesn't work on the **chosen** fields, do you know how solve that problem ?

Comment: Ask a new question with some background and gladly will help

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the better solution.

```
//trigger validation onchange
$('select').on('change', function() {
    $(this).valid();
});

$('form').validate({
    ignore: ':hidden', //still ignore Chosen selects
    submitHandler: function(form) { //all the fields except Chosen selects have already passed validation, so we manually validate the Chosen selects here            
        var $selects = $(form).find('select'),
            valid = true;
        if ($selects.length) {
            //validate selects
            $selects.each(function() {
                if (!$(this).valid()) {
                    valid = false;
                }
            });
        }
        //only submit the form if all fields have passed validation
        if (valid) {
            form.submit();
        }
    },
    invalidHandler: function(event, validator) { //one or more fields have failed validation, but the Chosen selects have not been validated yet
        var $selects = $(this).find('select');     
        if ($selects.length) {
            validator.showErrors(); //when manually validating elements, all the errors in the non-select fields disappear for some reason

            //validate selects
            $selects.each(function(index){
                validator.element(this);
            })
         }
    },
    //other options...
});
```

**Note:** You will also need to change the `errorPlacement` callback to handle displaying the error. If your error message is next to the field, you will need to use `.siblings('.errorMessageClassHere')` (or other ways depending on the DOM) instead of `.next('.errorMessageClassHere')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#formID").validationEngine({
     prettySelect : true,
     useSuffix: "_chzn"
});
```

[jQuery-Validation-Engine/demoChosenLibrary](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/blob/master/demos/demoChosenLibrary.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if($('form').valid() == true && $('.select-chosen').valid() == true){
        console.log("Valid form");
    } else {
        console.log("Invalid form");
    }
});
```

Remember to add `.select-chosen` class on each `select`s.

`$('.select-chosen').valid()` forces the validation for the hidden `select`s

http://jsfiddle.net/mrZF5/39/

Answer (score 0):

My form includes conditionally hidden fields, to prevent the hidden chosen fields failing validation I've extended the default ignore:hidden a little further:

```js
$.validator.setDefaults({ 
  ignore: ":hidden:not(.chosen-select + .chosen-container:visible)"  //for all select having class .chosen-select
    })
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me at all. The `.chosen-select + .chosen-container:visible` part actually selects the chosen's `<div>` and not the `<select>` which must be validated, so I'm unclear about how this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

In the year 2018 I am verifying that jQuery validate is complaining about an input field with no name. This input field is appended by the jQuery Chosen plguin.

[image]

This bug is happening before anything else when using chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40310699/4700162 i resolve the iussue:

Inside the file the Chosen.jquery.js, change

```
this.form_field_jq.hide().after(this.container);
```

with this:

```
this.form_field_jq.css('position', 'absolute').css('opacity', 0).after(this.container);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery validation for “chosen” plugin. Working fine for me.

```
$('.chosen').chosen({
        allow_single_deselect: true
    });
    $.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ":hidden:not(select)" });
        $('form').validate({
            highlight: function(element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        },
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorClass: 'help-block text-danger',
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

After calling chosen() use below jquery method

$("#id").css("display":"").addClass("sr-only");

sr-only is boot strap class

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it by doing the following:

This was for Chosen v1.8.7:

1. Open chosen.js and on line 199 locate this:

`this.form_field_jq.hide().after(this.container),`

2. Replace that with this:

`this.form_field_jq.addClass('chosen-master').after(this.container),`

3. Add these CSS attributes to that class:

```
.chosen-master {
  display: inline-block !important;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64491538/7353382