# How I can highlight as required field with "chosen" Plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

Following dropdown code and I want to this field as required but there is no checking for validation.

```
<select id="mood" rel="chosen" required="required" name="moodName">
<option value="">Select Option</option>
<option value="69">AGITATED</option>
<option value="115">ALOOF</option>
<option value="46">AMUSED</option>
</select>
```

**Validation Code**

```
$('#Form').validate();
```

How to validate as required field of chosen field when Submit form? like **"This field is required"**.

Comment: This solution works for me https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/515#issuecomment-33214050

Answer (score 12):

If you're using Chosen for all `select` elements, you can use this CSS to change make it visible (to DOM), but no opacity, no height, absolute position.

These CSS selectors target invalid select elements, with one of them targeting `multiple` adding a `15px` `margin-top` to center it on the multiselect elements.

```
select:invalid {
    height: 0px !important;
    opacity: 0 !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    display: flex !important;
}

select:invalid[multiple] {
    margin-top: 15px !important;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tripflex/2zdeu9oc/

Comment: This should have more upvotes considering its the most elegant solution and you can use it with CDN invocation of choosen.js...

Comment: what about on mobile screen

Comment: Chosen.JS doesn't support mobile

Answer (score 11):

I ended up using the workaround mentioned in https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/2075#issuecomment-193805605

That is, find the line in `chosen.jquery.js` that says

```
this.form_field_jq.hide().after(this.container);
```

and replace it by

```
this.form_field_jq.css('position', 'absolute').css('opacity', 0).after(this.container);
```

It is a hack to "make invisible" the `select` element instead of telling the browser to hide it. Hence Chrome will be able to find the element when it needs to show the "please select an item in the list" message.

Comment: There is a problem with this approach. You have to check that the "select" width is the same as the "chosen" one or the select could be selected without realizing

Comment: I would change it to:`this.form_field_jq.css('position', 'absolute').css('opacity', 0).css('width', 0).after(this.container);`

Comment: I had change this: `this.form_field_jq.css('position', 'absolute').css('opacity', 0).css('width', 0).after(this.container)`
For this: `this.form_field_jq.css('position', 'absolute').css('opacity', 0).css('height', 0).after(this.container)`
This works for me with BS4

Answer (score 1):

As 'Chosen' plugin creates some HTML markup & hides original html `<select>`.

To highlight/mark chosen element as error (by adding CSS class .error)
we need to override / modify default 'higlight' & 'unhiglight' functions:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ 
    ignore: ":hidden:not(select)",
    highlight: function( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
        if ( element.type === "radio" ) {
            this.findByName( element.name ).addClass( errorClass ).removeClass( validClass );
        } else {
            $( element ).addClass( errorClass ).removeClass( validClass );

            // chosen specific
            if( $(element).hasClass('chzn-done') ){
                //$( element ).parent().find('.chzn-container').addClass( errorClass ).removeClass( validClass );
                $('#' + element.id + '_chzn').addClass( errorClass ).removeClass( validClass );
            }
        }
    },
    unhighlight: function( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
        if ( element.type === "radio" ) {
            this.findByName( element.name ).removeClass( errorClass ).addClass( validClass );
        } else {
            $( element ).removeClass( errorClass ).addClass( validClass );

            // chosen specific
            if( $(element).hasClass('chzn-done') ){
                $('#' + element.id + '_chzn').removeClass( errorClass ).addClass( validClass );
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And some example CSS:

```
.chzn-container.error a{
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I bumped into this problem, so the way I solved it:

```
$("form").find('input, textarea, select').each(function() {
if($(this).prop('required')) {
    if(!$.trim(this.value).length) { do something ..}
                // this here checks if input is only spaces (prevents the html required fields to accept spaces as input)
} 
if(this.id == "selectBox"){
    if(this.value == ""){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#selectBox_chosen').addClass('redBorder');
    } else {
           $('#selectBox_chosen').removeClass('redBorder');
    }
}});
```

The css is just

```
.redBorder{ border: 1px solid red;)}
```

What this does is - it goes through all the input elements (in my form) and checks if they are empty or not and then checks for the specific search box styled with Chosen - if the given element is the one I need it sets the css to the generated by Chosen new element.

Works with IE 11 and most versions of Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of highlight do you want. Here you have an example of How I do validations including chosen required combo. Probably more info than you wanted, but I think that Without all is difficult to understand how does it works.

At first I use for validtion a class validate that I add or remove to elements when is necesarry. and I have the expecific CSS for chosen like this: `select.validate:invalid+.chosen-container`

so the full code will be:

```
/* CSS */
.validate:invalid, .validate:invalid+label, 
    select.validate:invalid+.chosen-container {
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px -1px red;
    background-color: #fdf0f0;
}
```

with this method:

```
function validateFields(formId) {
    var dataIsValid = false;
    var id = formId != '' && formId != undefined ? '#' + formId : ''
    if(jQuery(id + ' :invalid').length > 0) {
        jQuery(id + ' :valid').removeClass('validate');
        jQuery(id + ' :invalid').addClass('validate');
        openModal('invalidData');
    } else {
        jQuery(':valid').removeClass('validate');
        dataIsValid = true;
    }
    return dataIsValid;
}
```

and this for validate any form:

```
if(validateFields('formId')) {
    //TODO
}
```

This works fine with chosen for me

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same problem. @AlejandroVD's answer pointed me in the right direction (Github) where I eventually found these two responses:

- https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/pull/2594#issuecomment-229321471
- https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/pull/2594#issuecomment-593295199

I combined the JS from the first link with the CSS from the second and it worked well.

Specifically, here's what I did for Chosen v1.8.7:

1. Open chosen.js and on line 199 locate this:

`this.form_field_jq.hide().after(this.container),`

2. Replace that with this:

`this.form_field_jq.addClass('chosen-master').after(this.container),`

3. Add these CSS attributes to that class:

```
.chosen-master {
  display: inline-block !important;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
select:invalid {
    height: 0px !important;
    opacity: 0 !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    display: flex !important;
}

select:invalid[multiple] {
    margin-top: 15px !important;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.