# jquery validation doesn't work chzn-select

Tags: jquery, validation, select, jquery-chosen, jquery-form-validator

I'm using jquery validation. Other field validations are working well except `chzn-select`.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {   
        FormValidation.init();
    });

    $(function() {          
        $(".chzn-select").chosen();
    });
</script>
```

html code

```
<select name="op[]" class="chzn-select" style="width:400px;" required>
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">chose 1</option>
    <option value="2">chose 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232310/how-can-i-use-jquery-validation-with-the-chosen-plugin

Comment: i see that but how use code
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ":hidden:not(select)" })