# Validating select box with jquery validate and chosen plugins

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-chosen

I am trying to use validate and chosen plugin together. I am having the problem while validating select boxes. I found similar questions [How can I use jQuery validation with the "chosen" plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232310/how-can-i-use-jquery-validation-with-the-chosen-plugin) and [Chosen.js and validate jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387553/chosen-js-and-validate-jquery) but I couldn't find a way to import the solutions to my code :

```
<form  class='myform' id='producteditform'>
                    <input type='hidden' value='<? echo $row['id']; ?>' name='pkedit' id='pkedit'>                   
                    <input type='hidden' value='save' name='operation' id='operation'>
                    <p><label for='nameedit'>Product Name</label><em>*</em><input id='nameedit' name='nameedit' value='<? echo $row['pname']?>'/></p>
                    <p><label for='unitedit'>Unit</label><em>*</em><?
                        $query="select * from units";
                        $result=$mysqli->query($query);
                        if($result->num_rows==0)
                        echo "<a href='units.php?operation=insert'>No unit found. Please define a unit first</a>";
                        else{               
                        echo    "<select class='chosen' id='unitedit' name='unitedit'>";        
                            while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
                              echo  "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";
                            echo    "</select>";
                        }
                        $mysqli->close();               

                    ?></p>                    
                    <p><a class='button' class='button' id='saveedit'>Save</a>
                    <a class='button' id='canceledit' onclick='f()' >Cancel</a></p>
                    </form>
```

jquery code

```
$("#save").click(function () {
        if($("#producteditform").validate({ 
         ignore: [], 
                rules: {
                  nameedit: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength:100

                  },
                  unitedit:{
                    required: true,
                  }

                }
              }).form()
            )
        {
            // do sth

                })
        }
}
```

html rendered output

```
<form class="myform" id="productform" novalidate="novalidate">
                    <input type="hidden" value="insert" name="operation" id="operation">

                    <p><label for="name">Product Name</label><em>*</em><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></p>
                    <p><label for="unit">Unit</label><em>*</em><select class="chosen chzn-done" id="unit" name="unit" style="display: none;"><option value="">please choose..</option><option value="1">kgg</option></select><div id="unit_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single" style="width: 200px;" title=""><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chzn-single" tabindex="-1"><span>please choose..</span><div><b></b></div></a><div class="chzn-drop" style="left: -9000px; width: 198px; top: 24px;"><div class="chzn-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" style="width: 163px;"></div><ul class="chzn-results"><li id="unit_chzn_o_0" class="active-result result-selected" style="">please choose..</li><li id="unit_chzn_o_1" class="active-result" style="">kgg</li></ul></div></div></p>
                    <p><a class="button" id="save">Save</a>
                    <a class="button" id="cancel" onclick="f()">Cancel</a></p>                  
                    </form>
```

when I remove class='chosen' everything works fine when save button clicked, otherwise im getting error Uncaught Error: Failed to validate, found an element with no name assigned. See console for element reference.

Comment: You'll need to show a little more code and explain more about how this is supposed to work and what you want.  What `event` or function is calling your `if` statement?  What do you want to do if the form is valid?

Comment: Also, show your **rendered** HTML output.  Your raw PHP is useless for answering this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this instead.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // initialize the plugin on DOM ready
    $("#producteditform").validate({ 
        // all rules and options,
        rules: {
            nameedit: {
                required: true,
                maxlength:100
            },
            unitedit:{
                required: true,
            }
        }
    });

    // test for valid form
    $('#save').on('click' function() {
        if($("#producteditform").valid()) {
            // do this on valid form
        } else {
            // do this on invalid form
        }
    });

});
```

[`$('#producteditform').validate()` initializes the validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) on the `form`.

[`$('#producteditform').valid()` programmatically triggers an actual validation test](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) and returns a `true/false` boolean value.

---

Alternatively, since your `event` is the form `click` on `submit` event, then you simply use the built-in `submitHandler` callback function instead.  (There is no need to create another `click` handler.)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // initialize the plugin on DOM ready
    $("#producteditform").validate({ 
        // all rules and options,
        rules: {
            nameedit: {
                required: true,
                maxlength:100
            },
            unitedit:{
                required: true,
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // do this on valid form
        }
    });

});
```

**Full documentation:**

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

---

Until you show your HTML output instead of the PHP, here is a generic example of how to validate a `select` element:

**http://jsfiddle.net/6Dt7F/**

Important, the very first, or the default `option` in the `select` element must contain `value=""` or the `required` rule will fail.

```
<select name="field1">
    <option value="">please choose...</option>
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
    <option>option 3</option>
</select>
```

---

**EDIT**:

I still don't have enough code to make a working demo.  However, since the `chosen` plugin is hiding the actual form elements, you'll have to do the following...

1)  Target the actual form element that is going to get validated and pass the data, not the visual element created by `chosen`.

2)  [Enable jQuery Validate to work on hidden elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8565769/594235) by setting `ignore: []` option.

Try this...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // initialize the plugin on DOM ready
    $("#producteditform").validate({ 
        // all rules and options,
        ignore: [], // <-- option so that hidden elements are validated
        rules: {
            name: {  // <-- name of actual text input
                required: true,
                maxlength: 100
            },
            unit:{  // <-- name of actual select input
                required: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // do this on valid form
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: its still not working. Do I have to write the validate inside onready? Currently thats inside $("#save").click(function ().

Comment: @woryzower, yes, that is exactly the problem.  `.validate()` must be called inside DOM ready so that it's properly initialized.  You do not put it inside a click handler, since the `submitHandler` callback option already handles the click.  This is explained in the first part of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This occurs because Chosen inserts an input field which the user can search through the dropdown list with.

For some reason, this search field does *not* have a name tag (hence the error):

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="7">
```

The input doesn't have a class or ID either, which is probably why the console error is so vague. A quick fix is to give it a name:

```
$(".chzn-search input").attr('name', 'chzn-search');
```