# Not getting validation message for @Html.DropDownListFor() once Chosen jquery is used

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-chosen, html.dropdownlistfor

Code is given below:
 If i do not select any value in the combobox and press submit, no validation message is asked.

```
<tr>
            <td>Department </td>
            <td> : </td>
            <td class="@*@Model.NoEdit*@">    
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DepartmentId, new SelectList(Model.Departments, "SelectedDepartmentId", "DepartmentCode"), "-- Select Department--", new {@class = "chosen-select", id = "cboDeptartment" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartmentId)
            </td>
```

Comment: where is jquery code?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand you.Chosen is a jquery plugin Its available in this site http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Restating my brief comment as an answer. :-)

To get the validation messages, I use the same approach Joseph mentions, though I use an HTML class for those selects that I am using with Chosen. For example:

```
validator.settings.ignore = ":hidden:not(.select-chosen)";
```

To clear the validation message when a value is selected, you need to attach an event listener for "change" events and explicitly force revalidation of the select. So for example, assuming you have a variable `select` that references the select box:

```
select.on("change", function(evt, params) {
    $(evt.target).valid();
});
```

Chosen triggers those "change" events whenever it's value changes.

Comment: I have same problem I added `Validator.settings...` line but now when i click on the button my model dosn't apears any more

Answer (score 8):

Solved after a lot of research...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var validator = $("#Your_form_id").data('validator');
    validator.settings.ignore = ":hidden:not(select)";
});
```

Comment: Now its working but it does not remove the validation message when i select a value on to dropdownlist.It goes off only when i press Submit button.

Comment: Joseph, did you resolve the issue with clearing the validation message when a value is selected? I'm trying to resolve that one, now.

Comment: OK, found the solution. Assuming the select box is referenced by the variable `select`:

    `select.on('change', function(evt, params) {
        $(evt.target).valid();
    });`

This forces validation of the field.

Comment: Thanks @MikeBrennan, i ended up using bootstrap dropdown .but could you post it as an ans so that i could mark it as ans.. might help smone in future :)

Comment: @MikeBrennan where to add The select function I tried this `$(document).ready(function () {
                var validator = $("#form").data('validator');
                validator.settings.ignore = ":hidden:not(.chosen-select)"; });
     select: select.on('change', function (evt, params) { $(evt.target).valid(); });`

Answer (score 2):

So aligning the above answers properly

```
 $(function () {
        var validator = $("#Your_form_id").data('validator');
        validator.settings.ignore = ":hidden:not(.chosen-select)";
        $(".chosen-select").chosen();
        $("#Your_dropdown_id").change(function (evt, params) {
            $(evt.target).valid();
        })

    });
```