# ListBoxFor Client Validation ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is my Model :

```
public partial class TAUX
    {
        ....
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Select one At least")]
        public IEnumerable<short> SelectItems { set; get; }
    }
```

This is my View :

```
@model pfebs0.Models.TAUX
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/Content/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
...
            $(".chosen-select").chosen({ width: "100%"})
</script> 
...
            @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectItems, (ViewBag.CAT_ID as SelectList), new { @class = "chosen-select", data_placeholder = "Selection une Categorie..." })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectItems)
```

Client Validation dosn't work in my ListBox , but for other Attribute it works fine. How to fix it ?

Comment: This question has already been answered [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428907/required-attribute-on-generic-list-property

Comment: No I want Client Validation

Comment: You really should have jQuery.validate.unobtrusive in your bundles.. However, do you also have jQuery.Validate.js included somewhere?

Comment: yeah It's included in my parent View and I tried to add it in partial view but always the client side validation not working

Comment: Ahh.. Actually, I bet it is... The problem is that you're using chosen.jquery, which actually hides your real listbox, and creates a fake one, which most likely doesn't work with validation.  Try not using the chosen and see if it works.

Comment: Yes, you got right, So is there any way to fix that to got both chosen and Validation work together?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950610/not-getting-validation-message-for-html-dropdownlistfor-once-chosen-jquery-is it helped me but clearing message after validation dosn't worked take look please

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CAT_ID)`

change to

`@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectItems)`

Comment: This dosn't work Validation work's only for Server Side