# Required validation not working for dropdownlist in MVC4?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

Required field validation for dropdownlist not firing

**Model:**

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Mobilizations = new HashSet<Mobilization>();
    }    


    [Required(ErrorMessage="Select Designation")]
    public int? DESIGNATIONID { get; set; }

}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class userViewModel
{
    public User User { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "CONFIRM PASSWORD is required")]
    [Display(Name="CONFIRM PASSWORD")]      
    [Compare("PASSWORD",ErrorMessage="Password didnot match")]
    public string ComparePassword { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Designation> DesignationList { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {           

        var model = new userViewModel
        {
            DesignationList = _db.Designations.ToList()

        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

**View:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.User.DESIGNATIONID,new SelectList(Model.DesignationList,"ID","DESIGNATION"),"--Select Designation--",
new { @class = "chosen-select " })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.DESIGNATIONID)
```

All other validations are firing except for dropdownlist. What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried removing `@class = "chosen-select"` to check it works without the plugin (I think the problem is that chosen-select hides the 'real' select element and replaces it with its own html (hidden elements are not validated by default)

Comment: @ksg are you using any plugins ?

Comment: @StephenMuecke You are absolutely right.I removed the class and the validation works. But how can I use chosen plugin along with valdation.?

Comment: You need to configure jquery validation to validate hidden elements (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379307/jquery-chosen-dropdown-validation-client-site-doesnt-work/26392882#26392882)

Comment: DesignationId should be an int not nullable int

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I tried your solution and validation works :).But the problem is validation is still showing after you select an item.

Comment: Seems odd (the pugin should be updating the hidden select). I don't have access to VS right now but will run a test tomorrow.

Comment: @ksg, [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950610/not-getting-validation-message-for-html-dropdownlistfor-once-chosen-jquery-is) is probably what you need (but looks like a major failing with chosen-select if this kind of work around is required)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Thankyou very much and that was the work around needed.I came across similar issue with `jquery Select2` plugin also. Guess what.. the fix was same as that of chosen plugin..